# Difference-in-Difference with Logistic Regression, how to add mutliple fixed effects?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, plm

I'm using R and running a **Difference-in-difference (DID) regression with unbalanced panel data**.  Since my dependent variable is a dummy variable, my DID is therefore a DID with logistic regression, and I can run the DID (by adding an interaction term to the function) with *plm* package.

I am now trying to add **time fixed effect** and **county fixed effect** simultaneously to the regression.

I found in R we have a package called *alpaca* to do this.  However, When I try to run the regression with feglm(), it runs smoothly, but when adding the interaction term (DID estimator), it cannot work and shows "Error in qr.solve(MX * w.tilde, Mnu * w.tilde, epsilon) :
singular matrix 'a' in solve".

I'm wondering whether you have any suggestions to figure out what's wrong.

Also, do we have any other good ways to deal with a **"DID logistic regression with two-way fixed effects"** in R?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here, since it's conceptual in nature; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you, Robert, I will post the question to stats.stackexchange.com.  Many thanks!